# How do you prove whether there are four elements?

Tags: science-based, chemistry, low-fantasy

A person from our world visits a (low magic) fantasy universe. Now, obviously our hero considers our world's science to be more advanced than the pseudo medieval world he finds himself in. But he meets an alchemist buddy, who counters: how can he be sure of that? Perhaps the scientific principles of this new world are simply different from his. Perhaps in this world, the alchemical theory that there's four elements (fire, earth, wind and water) is true, instead of the 100+ elements that exist in the other world.

**How can they devise an experiment that will prove things one way or another?** Note that in obvious, day to day terms, everything seems quite normal.

Comment: This is a trivial question about how come that words have different meanings. For example, take the word "check". The original meaning is "the act of attacking opponent's king at the game of chess"; to understand how come it acquired the meaning "an order to a bank to pay a sum of money" you need to study the etymology of the word. Same with the word "element". Its original meaning is "first principle". Then it acquired the meaning "basic knowledge". The meaning "a chemical substance which is not a compound" is from the 19th century and would naturally be unknown to a medieval alchemist.

Comment: The point being that modern science has appropriated *a lot* of old and respectable words, assigning to them technical meanings which they had never had before. It is sad that many people nowadays know only the new and pedestrian meanings. For example, Euclid's [*Elements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_Elements) is not a book about hydrogen and oxygen.

Comment: @AlexP agree, my answer focuses on this other meaning of "element" as a principle  and how people ordered these principles in a drawing, or diagram, to provide proof.

Comment: First and foremost, to hell with the isekai! Second, basing the entire world on four elements is plausible only on a general standpoint as long as one doesn't delve into the finer details. Once evolution kicks in and new phenomenon begin to emerge, ESPECIALLY ones that tend to question the co-relation of the previously established elements and begin to lay a new foundation for more refined functionality and purpose, the whole system has to be re-invented.

Answer (score 5):

Q: *"Perhaps in this world, the alchemical theory that there's four elements (fire, earth, wind and water) is true, instead of the 100+ elements that exist in the other world. How can they devise an experiment that will prove things one way or another? Note that in obvious, day to day terms, everything seems quite normal."*

**The four elements are not substances**

They predate the Romans, but second century Gnostic Romans built a philosophy around these four elements. Chinese always had five elements. But both civilizations were very well aware of more than 4 *types of substances* ! These four elements are no "elements" like our 100+ elements from the periodic table.

The *concepts* of Fire, Earth, Air (or wind) and Water have nothing to do with single  substances like periodic system elements.

**The four elements represent stages, of phases**

In medieval science, the four elements symbolized stages of development, in a consistent, cyclic explanatory system: the fire (IGNIS) symbolizes the *start* of something, like spring season, you plant things. Air is what makes us live, move, communicate and solve problems. Earth is a symbol of persistence and consolidation, continuing the work and earn from it. Then it will rain, water will feed and resolve it all and leave the clay, for a new cycle.

The notice of this universal cycle, supposedly based on agricultural cycles, covered all aspects of science for ca 5000 years, until Leonardo could break out of the cage, using his fantasy. After Leonardo, science got much more complicated. The system of four elements remains alive in belief systems like astrology, alchemy, gnostics, hermeticists, some freemasons.. The *proof* is often presented as a diagram, showing the cyclic connections of the symbols, like this

[image]

The four elements system is actually one of the first *coherent models* to study processes, everything from crop growth to human life. Modern science has opened itself for much more complicated models than this. Fire, wind, earth and water cyclic explanations won't suffice anymore, to describe real life sequences of events, in a modern world. But in a stable and peaceful rural culture, the system did provide a calendar and directions for life.

Answer (score 3):

If with element you mean something that cannot be reduced to simpler terms, it's pretty straightforward: take element A and show that it is made by other substances. Which is what the early chemists did. If that happens, you are still following "our" chemistry.

**Fire**

Start with fire: you can't get a fire without a combustible and a comburent. Light a fire under a glass jar, and see how it gets off quickly. Apparently fire needs something to be present.

**Water**

Run a current through water, you will see it produces two different gases. As an element, it should be unrelated to "wind".

**Earth**

Just observe how certain types of earth are impermeable to water while other are not, or how from certain types can be smolten into giving metals while other not.

**Wind**

Place a mouse under an airtight glass jar with a lit candle, the mouse will die when the candle goes off. Place another mouse under an airtight glass jar, and it will die again. Place yet another mouse under an airtight glass jar with a plant, and it won't die that quickly. Apparently there are different kind of substances in the "wind"

Comment: The problem is that for the alchemist, the word *element* means something like "first principle", or "basic knowledge on a given subject", or maybe "one member of a series". The meaning "a chemical substance which is neither a compound nor a mixture" dates from the 19th century and was first used by Sir Humphry Davy. (Modern science has appropriated *a lot* of old and respectable words, assigning to them meanings which they had never had before.) How to convince the alchemist to abandom their own perfectly good meaning of the word element in favor of another is not easy.

Answer (score 2):

All of these experiements work by showing that each element can be converted into other elements or needs other elements to function.

## Water

Water in our world is hydrogen and oxygen. So, you need to see if it splits. Make the local version of a potato battery, stick 20 or so of them in series (they produce around 0.5 V, you'll need a few to get a decent experiment) and then get a glass of water, stick an anode and a cathode in it (like a graphite pencil) and wire it all together.

If water isn't an element, it should be divisible into two gases, oxygen and hydrogen. The bubbles produced by electrolysing water can be collected, and should ignite upon application of a flame. Somehow, water has been split into wind and fire- or maybe it hasn't, and nothing or steam is produced, and it doesn't ignite.

## Fire.

First, put a water plant under water in a glass set up like this. [image] and collect gaseous oxygen.

Light a candle under a glass jar. In theory, the fire should consume all the oxygen and then stop burning, as fire relies on oxygen, wind, to burn. You can then put a stick of wood inside, and see it dim and go out, and put it in the test tube with the oxygen, re-igniting a split.

This also shows that wind has different types with different properties.

## Air

You can show that there's different sorts of air. An air from fire that puts out fires, an air from life that enhances flames. You can also make an explosive air from metals, by dipping them in water and collecting the gas.

Separating out air itself is harder. Do they have any freezing magic? Filter air to remove the dust, and then cool it down till it turns into a liquid. Fractional distillation is used to do this.

## Earth

This one is harder to prove, since it requires serious technical knowledge to separate the elements, since earth covers a huge range of materials. Iron ore, tin ore, and dirt aren't that similar.

One way to do it is to find a depressed person and remove their spleen. Their mood won't improve, contrary to the theory that an excess of black fluid from the spleen causes depression, if they also adhere to the humour model of elements.

Answer (score 2):

### How the Alchemist would win the debate

All forms of matter your scientist would be able to create would be Earth, Water, Wind, and Fire: the problem is a matter of translation, not science.  Modern science has simply changed the labeling system, and this would soon become apparent after a short debate.

What alchemists called the 4 elements are what modern science calls the 4 states of matter: Solid, Liquid, Gas, and Plasma.  Modern science has done nothing to disprove the 4 states of mater (except for some debatable technicalities your scientist would need a modern super collider or cryogenics to prove.) Another high concept of the 4 elements theory is that all matter can have the properties of one element brought out by its interactions with other matter.  This is what we today call thermodynamics.  At most, the Scientist might be able to give the alchemists some helpful formulas to work with to better predict state changes.

So, the modern scientist can not actually disprove the 4 elements theory once they get the language barrier out of the way.  Next, the scientist would try to introduce the concept of atoms: which was also a commonly held belief among medieval alchemists.  In addition to the 4 states of matter, they also recognized the existence of atom and void.  The ancient Greeks theorized that all matter was made of indivisible microscopic stuff that exhibited mass based on how much void was between the atoms. Modern science still holds a very similar explanation of mass to this.

So, when the scientist tries to explain chemistry and atomic science, it would not be nearly as contradictory as it seems.  The scientist would simply need to describe what we call "elements" as "atomic patterns" and the two scientists could communicate as clearly as a high school teacher and his student.

Now, here is where you need to make science diverge in the new world.  Our own period table is based on the existence of the electron cloud levels (2,8,8,18,18,32,32...).  If this medieval universe has such things as 1/2 electrons, then the size of the periodic table would be doubled. All these new elements would confound his experiments leading to chemical reactions he would be unable to predict.  However, the Alchemist who has generations of blind experimental knowledge to pull from could correctly predict a wide variety of reactions for making his "potions".  So, even though the new world would still work on the same principles as ours, it would take a lot of work from either party to even partially reassemble the periodic table.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly the Four Element theory involves. If it literally claims there are only 4 elements and everything is made up from only one element, well, then the alchemist buddy is probably quite insane as everyone can see there are more then 4 different things in the world.
On the other side of the spectrum the Four Elements could be the equivalent of what we call quarks (in detail and complexity, not necessarily in properties). Maybe the low magic allows a level of "alchemy" that challenges what we can currently do with particle accelerators.

Depending on that, disproving the Four Element theory ranges from trivial to next to impossible.

For a more concrete answer, we'd need a more detailed description of this Four Element theory. As far as I know there is no single theory of that name in the real world, but a wide range of ideas and concepts that share some terminology.